# Any way of accessing an Android device through ADB without debug mode enabled?

Tags: android, adb, tablet, locked

Is there any way of accessing an android tablet through ADB without debug mode being enabled on the device? I'm locked out of an android tablet, trying to get back into it; there is no password reset and factory reset procedures aren't working. Debug is disabled on the device, and I can't get in to turn it on, so ADB can't find the device (at least as I understand it)

Comment: You might want to take what you posted and distill it into something a bit more concentrated. Imagine you're writing an e-mail to your coworker. It is very hard for us to read paragraphs and paragraphs and figure out what you want. Give a couple of sentences of background, explain what you need to, then state your question explicitly. That way, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the device through adb without enable the debugging mode .